# How to use Python3.4 with Anaconda?

Tags: python

I want Anaconda to use Python 3.4, but I don't know how to do it.

In Anaconda, Python version switching can be done using Anaconda Navigator, but Anaconda Navigator 1.9.7 does not seem to support Python3.4.

[image]

I need Python3.4 to use py2exe, so how can I use Python3.4 with Anaconda?

I tried the following code at conda prompt.

```
conda install python=3.4
```

However, I got the following error.

```
    PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating an environment? I'd refer to the documentation you might find that helpful here https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Try doing something like:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.4
conda install -n myenv py2exe
```

To create an environment and then select the environment in the Anaconda Navigator